# sum two textboxes whenever button is clicked

Tags: c#, textbox

Ok here is my question in detail. I have created textbox1 to contain a calculation, whenever I click btnOne, the txtbox1 will give the result. The second textbox called textbox2 will add the number within textbox1 every time I click btnTwo button. I have tried to use the below code, but it only adds the number in textbox1 as a text, thus puts the number next to number in textbox2, instead of summing them. How can I make it work?

```
string a;
void textbox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    a = textbox1.Text;
}

void btnTwo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    textbox2.Text += a.ToString();    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout the following link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse(v=vs.110).aspx

So you have a couple of options, if you can guarantee it's always going to be a number (you can't, but if you're just experimenting, go ahead) then use Parse.

So in code, change your a variable to an int then:

```
a = Int32.Parse(textbox1.Text);
```

...

```
int textbox1Number = Int32.Parse(textbox1.Test);
textbox2.Text = (a += textbox1Number).toString();
```

If you use += on two strings it concatenates them. You need int's to do the math.

Take a look at the tryParse methods to handle invalid entries for bonus points.

Answer (score 2):

You should *convert* the text into `Double` (ot `int`)

```
using System.Globalization;

    void btnTwo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      Double a;
      Double b;

      // Let's be generous and accept leading/trailing spaces
      if (!Double.TryParse(textbox1.Text.Trim(), NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out a)) {
        textbox2.Text = "First term is of incorrect format.";

        return;
      }

      if (!Double.TryParse(textbox2.Text.Trim(), NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out b)) {
        textbox2.Text = "Second term is of incorrect format.";

        return;
      }

      textbox2.Text = (a + b).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
```

Comment: I tried your answer but the NumberStyles and CultureInfo gives an error of "does not exist in the current context"..

Comment: @user3222961: do not forget to add "using System.Globalization;"

Comment: Hmm, ok I added "using System.Globalization", so now my build succeeds. But the textbox2 now states "Second term is of incorrect format." when btnTwo is clicked..

Comment: @user3222961: So the value in the textbox2.Text is not a double. What's in the textbox2 then? Try put 123 into textbox2

Comment: The value in textbox2 is int but I tried both "double a" and "!Double.TryParse"; and "int a" and "!Int32.TryParse" which both of them gave the same text..

Comment: When I write an integer into both textbox1 and textbox2, the calculation works. But if I dont write anything to textbox2, and click the button to add from textbox1, it gives the text of"Second term is ..."

Comment: @user3222961: "int" is not a double value; run your program; put, say 123 into textbox1, then put 456 into textbox2 and, finally, click btnTwo

Comment: @user3222961: what the behavior do you expect then? You can add integers, you can add floats (say 1.23 and 4.56), but if you want to compute any formulae you should parse them, create a syntax tree, convert into reversed polish format and, finally, execute

Comment: Thanks, thats what I said in my latest comment. It sums them when I do it manually, but if I don't write anything into textbox2, and expect it to add the value from textbox1 automatically, it gives the "text", instead of the calculation. I used int a; !Int32.TryParse and wrote numbers as you suggested into the textboxes..

Answer (score 0):

Operator **+** will concatenate strings. So you have to convert them to int before adding them :

```
if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox2.Text)) 
    textbox2.Text = a;
else if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(a)) 
    textbox2.Text = Convert.toInt32(textbox2.Text) + Convert.toInt32(a);
```

Comment: If you are not checking for empty, convert will throw exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
 txt2.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(txt1.Text) + Convert.toInt32(a);
```

Comment: This will never assign. First time txt2.Text will be empty always.

Comment: If you are not checking for empty, convert will throw exception.

Comment: The code you give returns an error of cannot convert type int to string.

Comment: Declare your a as int @user3222961

Answer (score 0):

**Remove:**

```
string a;
 void textbox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      a = textbox1.Text;
 }
```

**Replace:**

```
 void btnTwo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {            
      textbox2.Text += a.ToString();    
 }
```

**With:**

```
 void btnTwo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {            
     textbox2.Text = int.TryParse(textbox2.Text) + int.TryParse(textbox1.Text);    
 }
```

Comment: The last code you give, gives an error of "Cannot implicitly convert type int to string."

Answer (score 0):

do it like this

```
void btnTwo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {            
     int someInt,someInt2;
     if(int.TryParse(a.Trim(),out someInt) && int.TryParse(textbox2.Text.Trim(),out someInt2))
      textbox2.Text = (someInt + someInt2).ToString();    
 }
```

Comment: I tried it but the textbox2 is empty even though I click btnTwo.

Comment: check the values of someInt1 and someInt2.